# Ways to make pandas code with time differences faster

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, performance

I have the following code in pandas, where I am trying to find the maximum difference of values across a 24-hour period for each of the capacity levels. I have tried optimizing the code, and this is what I have. From my tests, I know that the biggest bottleneck is looping over each hour in time_periods. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Note that I know that I can take the hour delta calculation outside, but this doesn't really save much time.

```
def classify_capacity_category(percentage_capacity):
    return round(percentage_capacity / 10)

df = hist_one.copy()
df.loc[df["Value"] < 0, "Value"] = 0
df["EffectiveDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["EffectiveDate"])

capacity_levels = [i for i in range(11)]
time_periods = [i for i in range(1, 24)]

# Calculate percentage capacity for each row
df['PercentageCapacity'] = df['Value'] / df['capacity'] * 100

# Classify each row into a capacity category
df['CapacityCategory'] = df['PercentageCapacity'].apply(classify_capacity_category)

max_ramp_rates = {capacity_level: {hour: 0 for hour in time_periods} for capacity_level in capacity_levels}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cap_level = row["CapacityCategory"]
    df["hour_delta"] = (df["EffectiveDate"] - row["EffectiveDate"]).astype('timedelta64[s]')
    df["hour_delta"] = (df["hour_delta"].dt.total_seconds() / 3600).round()
    
    for hour in time_periods:
        part = df.loc[df["hour_delta"] == hour]
        cur_max = part["Value"].max()
        if cur_max - row["Value"] > max_ramp_rates[cap_level][hour]:
            max_ramp_rates[cap_level][hour] = cur_max - row["Value"]

print(max_ramp_rates)
df_max_ramp_rates = pd.DataFrame(max_ramp_rates)

df_max_ramp_rates
```

Here is a dictionary sample of the data:

```
{'EffectiveDate': {6354838: '2021-07-15 00:24:06',
  6354839: '2021-07-15 00:54:00',
  6354840: '2021-07-15 00:57:02',
  6354841: '2021-07-15 01:24:00',
  6354842: '2021-07-15 01:54:06',
  6354843: '2021-07-15 02:24:00',
  6354844: '2021-07-15 02:24:06',
  6354845: '2021-07-15 02:27:02',
  6354846: '2021-07-15 02:54:00',
  6354847: '2021-07-15 02:54:04'},
 'Value': {6354838: 10,
  6354839: 10,
  6354840: 10,
  6354841: 20,
  6354842: 20,
  6354843: 140,
  6354844: 140,
  6354845: 160,
  6354846: 240,
  6354847: 250},
 'capacity': {6354838: 619,
  6354839: 619,
  6354840: 619,
  6354841: 619,
  6354842: 619,
  6354843: 619,
  6354844: 619,
  6354845: 619,
  6354846: 619,
  6354847: 619}}
```

Comment: Please add representative data.

Comment: 1) work on numpy arrays instead of dataframes 2) sort data by datetime if not sorted 3) keep track of min/max indices neighbouring current row, next row time periods boundaries will not be very far, thus you can find them faster that searching through whole dataset

Comment: `for hour in time_periods` + `df["hour_delta"] == hour` is a red flag. Please consider using the `groupby` function for this. `row["Value"]` is recomputed while it can be pre-computed once (CPython performs nearly no optimization of the code).

Comment: @dankal444 Using numpy arrays made it much faster, thank you.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what `df_max_ramp_rates` actually represents? For your sample data there are only three non-zero values.

Answer (score 0):

I had a difficult time following your code, and believing the statement of intent at face value:

> I am trying to find the maximum difference of values across a 24-hour period for each of the capacity levels

I do not think that it does what it was meant to do. I demonstrate a somewhat less surprising method that does not "leave Pandas":

```py
import pandas as pd

hist_one = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'EffectiveDate': {6354838: '2021-07-15 00:24:06',
                       6354839: '2021-07-15 00:54:00',
                       6354840: '2021-07-15 00:57:02',
                       6354841: '2021-07-15 01:24:00',
                       6354842: '2021-07-15 01:54:06',
                       6354843: '2021-07-15 02:24:00',
                       6354844: '2021-07-15 02:24:06',
                       6354845: '2021-07-15 02:27:02',
                       6354846: '2021-07-15 02:54:00',
                       6354847: '2021-07-15 02:54:04'},
     'Value': {6354838: 10,
               6354839: 10,
               6354840: 10,
               6354841: 20,
               6354842: 20,
               6354843: 140,
               6354844: 140,
               6354845: 160,
               6354846: 240,
               6354847: 250},
     'capacity': {6354838: 619,
                  6354839: 619,
                  6354840: 619,
                  6354841: 619,
                  6354842: 619,
                  6354843: 619,
                  6354844: 619,
                  6354845: 619,
                  6354846: 619,
                  6354847: 619}}
)

df = hist_one.copy()
df['Value'] = df.Value.clip(lower=0)
df['EffectiveDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EffectiveDate'])
df = df.set_index('EffectiveDate')
df['PercentageCapacity'] = df['Value'] / df['capacity'] * 100
df['CapacityCategory'] = df['PercentageCapacity'] // 10

resampled = df.groupby('CapacityCategory').resample(rule='1H', origin='start_day')
summands = pd.merge(
    left=resampled.Value.max().reset_index('EffectiveDate'),
    right=(-resampled.Value.min()).reset_index('EffectiveDate'),
    suffixes=('_upper', '_lower'), on='CapacityCategory',
).set_index('EffectiveDate_upper', append=True)[['Value_upper', 'Value_lower']]

diff = summands.sum(axis=1).groupby(level=['CapacityCategory', 'EffectiveDate_upper']).max()
print(diff)
```

This produces a `df` of:

```
                     Value  capacity  PercentageCapacity  CapacityCategory
EffectiveDate                                                             
2021-07-15 00:24:06     10       619            1.615509               0.0
2021-07-15 00:54:00     10       619            1.615509               0.0
2021-07-15 00:57:02     10       619            1.615509               0.0
2021-07-15 01:24:00     20       619            3.231018               0.0
2021-07-15 01:54:06     20       619            3.231018               0.0
2021-07-15 02:24:00    140       619           22.617124               2.0
2021-07-15 02:24:06    140       619           22.617124               2.0
2021-07-15 02:27:02    160       619           25.848142               2.0
2021-07-15 02:54:00    240       619           38.772213               3.0
2021-07-15 02:54:04    250       619           40.387722               4.0
```

`summands` of:

```
                                      Value_upper  Value_lower
CapacityCategory EffectiveDate_upper                          
0.0              2021-07-15 00:00:00           10          -10
                 2021-07-15 00:00:00           10          -20
                 2021-07-15 01:00:00           20          -10
                 2021-07-15 01:00:00           20          -20
2.0              2021-07-15 02:00:00          160         -140
3.0              2021-07-15 02:00:00          240         -240
4.0              2021-07-15 02:00:00          250         -250
```

and a `diff` of

```
CapacityCategory  EffectiveDate_upper
0.0               2021-07-15 00:00:00     0
                  2021-07-15 01:00:00    10
2.0               2021-07-15 02:00:00    20
3.0               2021-07-15 02:00:00     0
4.0               2021-07-15 02:00:00     0
```

This seems correct to me: within category 0, the maximum 0-hour diff is 0, and the maximum 1-hour diff is 10 (etc.)

This should have several performance advantages, and not only because it is vectorised. It shortcuts some difference calculations by doing a minimum and maximum on the summand terms, and only evaluates times for which resampled hour values appear in the original data - not all possible hours.